# Mysql - Improving consultation query in 'group by'

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, sum

I have a query with 'group by':

```
SELECT date_audience, 
    Sum( If( quality_apuration = '1', 1, 0 ) ) AS very_good, 
    Sum( If( quality_apuration = '2', 1, 0 ) ) AS good, 
    Sum( If( quality_apuration = '3', 1, 0 ) ) AS bad, 
    Sum( If( quality_apuration = '4', 1, 0 ) ) AS no_apuration, 
    Count(quality_apuration) AS total 

    FROM pp_base 

    WHERE date_audience >= '2011-01-01' AND date_audience <= '2011-02-28'

    GROUP BY date_audience ORDER BY date_audience ASC
```

Where to return the following result (or see http://jsbin.com/imuru5/):

[image: Table Results]

As the table X has foreign key to another table Y, eventually someone will ask to include one more item in the table Y, for example: 'exccelent', 'regular', etc. And I will also have to adjust the schedule as php  $query[0]['very_good'], $query[0]['good'],  $query[0]['bad'], etc, adding among other items, spending more time .

Does anyone have any idea how I can improve this query, in order to automate the results?

Thanks, Vinicius.

Comment: I don't see any GROUP BY in your query.

Comment: Make sure date_audience is indexed. Also, don't use if/sum. You can do this query with plain count()

Comment: I think any attempt at automating this would require the construction of dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two options.

**1) Dealing with it in the application**. The following query will perform neccesary aggregation in the database and return 4 rows for each date_audience (one for each value of quality_apuration).

```
select date_audience
      ,quality_apuration
      ,count(*)
  from pp_base
 where date_audience >= date '2011-01-01' 
   and date_audience <= date '2011-02-28'
 group 
    by date_audience
      ,quality_apuration
 order
    by date_audience
      ,quality_apuration;
```

This is preferred when you expect changes to the quality_apuration values.

**2) Dealing with it in the database**. You could define a view like the following:

```
create or replace view pp_view as
   select date_audience
         ,sum(case when quality_apuration = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as very_good
         ,sum(case when quality_apuration = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as good
         ,sum(case when quality_apuration = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as bad
         ,sum(case when quality_apuration = '4' then 1 else 0 end) as no_apuration
         ,count(quality_apuration) as total
     from pp_base 
    group 
       by date_audience;
```

...from the application you would then select as follows:

```
select ...
  from pp_view
 where date_audience >= date '2011-01-01' 
   and date_audience <= date '2011-02-28'
 order 
    by date_audience;
```

Of course, whenever you add another value for quality_apuration, you would have to modify the view definition. Still, it's better than modifying all queries.